# In View pager Tab Layout, tab heading is not coming to center and tab indicator is not occupying whole layout

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

In View pager Tab Layout, when ever I have single tab, tab heading is not coming to center and tab indicator  is not occupying whole layout, but when there is more than 1 tabs its dividing and occupying whole. I have used custom tab layout class.

My custom tab layout code is :-

public class OPTCustomTab extends TabLayout {

```
public OPTCustomTab(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public OPTCustomTab(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public OPTCustomTab(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    ViewGroup tabLayout = (ViewGroup) getChildAt(0);
    int childCount = tabLayout.getChildCount();

    if (childCount != 0) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int tabMinWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels / childCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; ++i) {
            tabLayout.getChildAt(i).setMinimumWidth(tabMinWidth);
        }
    }

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

}

I have tried giving this,

app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
app:tabGravity="fill"